# how to override imported .css file in react? (Need to override some values in quill css file)

Tags: css, react-css-modules, react-quill

I am using Quill.js to have a wysiwyg editor, and it recommends to import the snow.css file as the starting point, but I can't seem to override the styling from that file. For instance:

```
import '../path/snow.css' // The css file for the basic styling
import styles from '../path/component.module.scss' // the module 

 return (
      <div className={[styles.newsWrapper].join(' ')}>
        <div data-cy="status-editor-panel" className={styles.newseditor}>
          <ReactQuill
            className={styles.quill}
            theme="snow"
            onChange={handleChange}
            modules={{}}
            placeholder={"Start typing to create your article."}
          />
          {/* { richText.count > 0 && <Grid item px={3}>{`${richText.count} total words`}
        </Grid> } */}
        </div>
        {error && (
          <p style={{ color: "red" }}>
            Please write something about your article
          </p>
        )}
        <div className={"postbuttonwrapper"}></div>
        <Button
          className={styles.postbutton}
          onClick={confirmStepOne}
          fullWidth
          variant="contained"
        >
          Next
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }

I want to make the outlines zero. I'm importing the styling from '../path/component.module.scss' and the module is *after* the import. I don't know how to order the styling.
```